Increasing the height in pixels does not increase the size of the element
Currently I'm working with material UI where I have a scrolling list of items that I would like to make bigger. However, when I increase the size of the height in pixels I noticed that the height of the items does not get bigger than 140px.
Here is the code
  <Box
        display="flex"
        flexDirection="column"
        justifyContent="center"
        height={800}
        overflow={'auto'}
        maxWidth="xl"
      >
        {items.map((item, index) => (
          <Paper
            key={index}
            sx={{ p: 2, height: '200px', width: '75%', margin: '50px auto' }}
          >
            <Typography sx={{ pb: 2 }} textAlign="center">
              {item}
            </Typography>
            <Box>
              {/* On top of this we need to make a scrolling container? */}
              <Grid container spacing={2}>
                <Grid item xs={12}>
                  {/* a list of items for this date */}
                  {/* <Item>xs=1.5</Item> */}
                  {/* button here to add items? */}
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
              <Button
                variant="outlined"
                key={'addEntry'}
                onClick={addEntry}
                sx={{
                  my: 2,
                  color: 'white',
                  display: 'block',
                  fontFamily: 'monospace',
                }}
              >
                +
              </Button>
            </Box>
          </Paper>
        ))}
      </Box>

As you can see, in the <Paper> component, I have the height of my items that I would like to increase but it does not increase past 150px. The only way around this is by removing the height of the encapsulating <Box> element but I would like to keep my items in here. Is the main reason for my issue the size of the  element?

This happens because your <Box> height is superior than the Paper height you can come up with these solutions
Option 1 (100% box height with constant Paper height)
<Box
  ...
  height="100%"
  ...
>

<Paper
  ...
  sx={{ p: 2, height: '140px', width: '75%', margin: '50px auto' }}
  ...
>

Option 2 (Constant Box height and Paper with minHeight)
<Box
  ...
  height="800px"
  ...
>

<Paper
  ...
  sx={{ p: 2, minHeight: '140px', width: '75%', margin: '50px auto' }}
  ...
>

